# PHP + Wordpress: getting a session variable on wp-login.php template

Tags: php, wordpress, session, global-variables, scope

I am editing wp-login.php to create a custom login screen. Maybe there's a better way to do this, so if anyone has experience with that any comments are welcome.

Within my theme's functions.php I start a session:

```
function init_sessions() {
    if (!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}
add_action('init', 'init_sessions');
```

Within my theme file I set a session variable:

```
// Check if we've submitted a language
if($_GET['id'] == 'en') {
    $_SESSION['bam_lan'] = 'en';
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['bam_lan'])) {
    $_SESSION['bam_lan'] = 'es';
}

// Set language
$bam_lan = $_SESSION['bam_lan'];
```

Within wp-login.php, `echo $_SESSION['bam_lan'];` doesn't echo anything.

How do I get a global session variable which is set in my theme's functions.php from wp-login.php??

Thanks!

Comment: *"no need to comment on the practicality"* - so we should not tell you that yours does not work? Uh?

Comment: Have you enabled WP_DEBUG? Also `session_start` returns a value, check if it could start. Then keep in mind that it needs to set a cookie, for which headers must be sent. See as well the worpdress program flow for some orientation: http://toolpress.de/tools/Toolpress_-_Wordpress-3.0-Program-Flow-0.2-2010-06-28.pdf - Init is when theme is loaded. I suspect you need to do the action ealier. Also look into `wp-login.php` because it is not the standard entry-point (but it should trigger as well the load order as outlined, take care for little differences).

Answer (score 1):

wp-login.php executes before functions.php and before 'init' action.